# How to concatenate two different values from two different columns with comma " , " using TSQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, concatenation, coalesce

I would like to know how to concatenate two different values from two different columns from a SQL table using TSQL ?

[image]

As you can see, I would like to concatenate those two different columns X e Y, resulting in the follow column table:

[image]

Which query should be used here ?

Comment: The question is: why do you want to do that in the first place? Formatting, in general, should be left to the client language.

Comment: provide dataset rather than attaching a screenshot. it is time consuming to replicate the same dataset.

Comment: Do any of the columns have a data type other than `pixel`? Is the "NULL" a picture, a string or a `null`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `concat` as

```
SELECT 
    Source, QtyPrevious, QtyToday, ProductPrevious, ProductToday, 
    AvaDatePr, AvaDateToday, Clusters, CONCAT(X, '', Y) as Z 
from your_table_name;
```

Answer (score 1):

if the datatype is numeric types(int,bigint, tinyint,smallint,etc) then you need to cast it to string before you concatenate. if the datatype is string(varchar,char,nvarchar,nchar) then you can directly use `concat` function

```
select concat(cast(column_1 as varchar) ,cast(column_2 as varchar))

select concat(column_1,column_2)
```

> another workaround, if the columns are string datatype, then

```
select column_1+column_2
```

> sample

```
with cte as (select 1 as id, 'name' as Field1, 'job' as Field2, '1test1' as Field1value , '2test1' as Field2value 
union select 2 as id, 'name' as Field1, 'job' as Field2, '1test1' as Field1value , '2test2' as Field2value 
union select 2 as id, 'age' as Field1, 'town' as Field2, '13' as Field1value , 'town1' as Field2value )
select 'select percentage from table2 where '+Field1+' ='+ ''''+Field1value+ ''''+' and '+Field2+' = '+  ''''+Field2value+ '''' from cte
```

> result

[image]

> *Note: null value in any one column will have result as null*

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `+` to concatenate charcaters.

**Query**

```
select *, x + ',' + y as z
from your_table_name;
```

If there is a null value in any of the columns, then the concatenation results to a `null` value.

To handle the `null` value in any of the column

**Query**

```
select *,
case 
  when x is null and y is not null then y
  when y is null and x is not null then x
  when x is null and y is null then null
  else x + ',' + y end as z
from your_table_name;
```